# How to get a list of vendors/brands that supply Walmart.com

Tags: data-request

I am trying to figure out the best way to compile a list of vendors or brands in the Walmart.com eCommerce store.

Would the best way to go about this be scraping their website or is there another way to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 0):

Bloomberg Professional has supply chain data for public companies like Walmart. Of course, it is only available to paying subscribers.